# How do I remove the opacity from UIPickerView on the unselected rows

Tags: ios, swift, uipicker

I'm trying to remove the opacity from the pickerview as part of my slot machine project. I'm trying to make the rows on the pickerview to have the same look like the selected row.
 I looked all over but could not find something about that. I tried several things like:

pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0)

and any other things like that.. Any Help?

Comment: I don't see API for that. Seems like you can't do it without hacking.

Comment: How am I doing it? (I'm new user, if you can give me more information I will be thankful)

Comment: I haven't done that and I wouldn't do it at all if a system component doesn't provide API.

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

UIColor Picker has an option with name supportsAlpha as Bool value, You can easily set it to false.

```
pickerView.supportsAlpha = false
```